# Creating a page that requires the user to answer a math equation before opening the home page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make my `index.html` be a page that asks the user a question before allowing him/her to access `home.html`. (The fact that the user could simply open up `site_name.com/home` is something I'll deal with later lol. Bear with me for now).

Here's my game plan:

When the user opens the page, a random arithmetic question will be pasted into a div. The arithmetic question will be 2 single-digit positive integers and one of the binary operations `+`, `-` or `*`. The answer somehow needs to be stored as a global variable (This is one of the things I'm stuck on). I've constructed the following function for that purpose.

```
    var randquest = function ()
    {
        var ops = ["+", "-", "*"];
        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10);
        var num2 = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10);
        var thisOp = ops[Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10) % 3];

        var myDiv = document.getElementById("questiondiv");
        var myNewNode = document.createElement('div class="outerdiv" id="questiondiv"')
        var myContent = document.createTextNode("<p><b>Question:</b> " + num1 + " " + thisOp + " " + num2 + "</p>");
        var myNewNode.appendChild(myContent);
        var myDiv.appendChild(myNewNode);

        answer = new String();
        switch (thisOp)
        {
            case "+"
            {
                answer = (num1 + num2).toString();
            }
            case "-"
            {
                answer = (num1 - num2).toString();
            }
            case "*"
            {
                answer = (num1 * num2).toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I need a function to check that what a user inputs into the input text cell with id `ans` is the correct answer to the question that was generated.

```
    var checker = function()
    {
        var ipt = document.getElementById("ans").value;
        if (ipt != answer)
        {
            alert("Wrong answer. Entrance not granted.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Open up home.html
        }
    }
```

But for that to work, I somehow need answer to have been a global variable, and I somehow need a procedure inside the `else` statement that opens up `home.html`. How do I do this? I'm at a roadblock.

Here's the whole page thus far, if you care to see it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Sentinel page 
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {

        }
        .innerdiv
        {
            z-index: -1;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 700px;
        }
        .outerdiv
        {
            width: 700px;
            border: 2px solid #FFF;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-color: blue;
        }
        .outerdiv:nth-of-type(2n+0)
        {
            background: grey;
        }
        .outerdiv:nth-of-type(2n+1)
        {
            background: #FFFFCC;
        }
        #headerdiv
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #maindiv
        {

        }
        #footerdiv
        {

        }
        p
        {
            color: blue;
        }
        h1
        {
            color: red;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        var randquest = function ()
        {
            var ops = ["+", "-", "*"];
            var num1 = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10);
            var num2 = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10);
            var thisOp = ops[Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10) % 3];

            var myDiv = document.getElementById("questiondiv");
            var myNewNode = document.createElement('div class="outerdiv" id="questiondiv"')
            var myContent = document.createTextNode("<p><b>Question:</b> " + num1 + " " + thisOp + " " + num2 + "</p>");
            var myNewNode.appendChild(myContent);
            var myDiv.appendChild(myNewNode);

            answer = new String();
            switch (thisOp)
            {
                case "+"
                {
                    answer = (num1 + num2).toString();
                }
                case "-"
                {
                    answer = (num1 - num2).toString();
                }
                case "*"
                {
                    answer = (num1 * num2).toString();
                }
            }
        }
        var checker = function()
        {
            var ipt = document.getElementById("ans").value;
            if (ipt != answer)
            {
                alert("Wrong answer. Entrance not granted.");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Open up home.html
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="innerdiv">

    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="headerdiv">
        <h1>my_site</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="introdiv">
        <p>Welcome to my site. Before you can enter the main page, I need to make sure you're human. So please answer the question below.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="questiondiv">
        <!-- Div to house the arithmetic quesiton -->
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="answerdiv">
        <p><b>Answer:</b></p> <input type="text" id="ans"> <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checker">
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="footerdiv">
        <p>Last modified: 03/31/2014</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JavaScript, you risk people being able to use developer tools to find the answer to use an automated system to get in. Just because a user can't see the answer doesn't mean it's not in the HTML code. The browser has access to this answer, and a bot attempting to get into the site will also have access to it. If you hit the F12 key in Internet Explorer, you'll get developer tools, including a DOM explorer, which will give you access to the entire page in raw HTML code.

You should use something like PHP for this situation. PHP is much easier for printing elements and text than JavaScript, and it's server-side, so code is executed on the web server. Here's how you should set it up.

When the user goes to the website for the first time, the server will redirect to the page `captcha.php`. Pages other than `index.php` (the home page, I'm assuming) should also redirect to `captcha.php` if they haven't answered the question. This pagehas the random math problem generated by PHP, and the `<form>` uses two POST variables: the answer to the problem, and a unique CAPTCHA code for each question, which is in the `<form>` already through an `<input type="hidden">` tag. PHP can put this unique CAPTCHA session code into the `value` attribute without JavaScript. When the question is answered, the browser should go to a page to check the answer (ex. `captcha_check.php`).

Example `captcha.php` page:

```
<p>Math problem generated by PHP</p>
<form action="captcha_check.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha-id" value="CAPTCHA code generated by PHP" />
    <input type="text" name="captcha-solution" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

The `captcha_check.php` page should use the CAPTCHA session code and solution sent to it by POST to check, and redirect to the `captcha.php` page is the answer is wrong, or redirect to the `index.php` page otherwise. Before redirecting to the `index.php` page if the answer is correct, the `captcha_check.php` page should store a cookie for the session. This way, the cookie is sent to all pages in the HTTP headers, so every page can verify the session. The cookie can remain on the computer forever if you'd like, letting the user visit multiple sessions without the burden.

In general, math problems for CAPTCHAs are not secure, but they're much easier than the standard RECAPTCHAs by Google. If you're looking for a secure CAPTCHA that isn't completely irritating, take a look at PlayThru by areyouahuman.com. http://areyouahuman.com/site-owners/playthru/

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your variable `ipt` globally, i.e., outside of the function definition.

```
var ipt;

var checker = function() {
    // set ipt value here. 
}
```